# Comparing two Strings and display percentage match

Tags: excel, uipath, rpa

I work as a project planner. And I receive submittals for project ideas regularly. And some of these ideas have been rejected previously.

However, customers sometimes re-submit these ideas repeatedly, sometimes with the exact description and sometimes with slight changes to the project description.

I am trying to develop a way to filter out and catch re-submitted project ideas and similar ones by comparing them to an exacting date base by doing stings comparison to find the similarities and show the percentage %.

For example:

- 1- “Build me a new bridge” vs. “Build me a new bridge” would return
  100%
- 2-“Build me a new bridge “ vs. “ Build me a bridge “ would return 80%

Is there a way to implement these functionalities on MS Excel or UiPath StudioX?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps find() on each word looking in the other string, if found limit to 1 then count out of total... But you don't show what you have tried so this is just a hint for you to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

So, this may be what you mean, but you might need to expand it:

```
=(COUNT(IFERROR(FIND(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",","),",",,1,,),A2,),0))/COUNTA(IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",","),",",,1,,),0)))*100
```

Updated with your last two examples and it works:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tried the answer you have provided, and it did not work. I keep getting 100% for all cells. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FNxh4LIex0_92LywoSt_1p4qAGhXXXpY/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: My answer works, but I won't be downloading your sheet to correct yours, as I don't want a virus. You need to check the detail and see what has changed between yours and mine.

Comment: I have uploaded the picture, can you tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: I have updated with another image of mine - including selecting the 4th example so you can check that formulae with yours.